# 2 languages, 3 domains

Tags: multi-language, domain-mapping

I have a site that uses WPML for showing the website in 2 languages.
Now I want to add a domain alias for 1 of these languages. And I don't want it to be a redirect.
For example:
sitename.nl should show the Dutch version.
sitename.com should show the English version.
sitename.be should also show the Dutch version.

In WPML I can only enter one URL per language, so I'm not sure how to solve this.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want sitename.nl and sitename.be to show the same version and not redirect? What will your canonical link be or do you want duplicate content?

Comment: Most of the people in Belgium speak Dutch as well... So they can read the .NL website... But for them it will feel more secure if they visit a .BE domain. Same will happen for Germany and Austria. Adding another language to WPML while the language is exactly the same doesn't feel right.

Comment: That is a valid point. However, you should consider the SEO points such as duplicate content. If you want to stick with different domains, I personally would probably add a new language with most/exactly the same translation. This would allow you to set proper [`hreflang`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) tags